# Throwing an Exception? Ignoring something in a double

Tags: java, exception

In my program I am allowing the user to enter information into Scanner for a bookstore, and calculating things with it. The part I am having trouble with is when the user enter the cost of the book, the program crashes because it does not account for a "$" since cost is a double. I thought maybe I could throw an exception or something? Or maybe turning cost into a string searching for the the "$" and then turning cost back into a double since it is needed for calculations. Any ideas?

Heres what I have so far:

```
public static final String SENTINEL = "N"; // for sentinel

public static void main(String[]args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); // initializing Scanner
    userInput(input);
}

      public static void userInput(Scanner input){

    // Initializing variables
    System.out.print("Do you want to add a book order? (Enter Y for yes/ N for no): ");
        String userInput = input.next();
    String code = "";
    double cost = 0.0; // this is the variable im talking about
    int numBooks = 0;
    int enroll = 0;
    String reqOp = "";
    String newUse = "";
    int count = 0;

    while(!userInput.equals(SENTINEL)){ // while userInput does not equal "quit" continue
        System.out.print("Code: ");
        code = input.next(); // accepting user input
        System.out.print("Cost of single copy: " );

        cost = input.nextDouble(); // here is where I am having issues

           /* I was thinking of putting in an if statment that would be
             if( user inputs a $) then{
              throw something
             }
                But Im not sure what exactly to put in the if statment
                or what i should throw */
        System.out.print("Current number of books: ");
        numBooks = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Prospective class enrollment: ");
        enroll = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Is this Required or Optional?(Enter R or O): ");
        reqOp = input.next();
        System.out.print("Is it New or Used?(Enter N or U): ");
        newUse = input.next();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could instead use a regular expression to filter the value of `next` before converting it to double instead of using `nextDouble`.

```
cost = Double.parseDouble(input.next().replaceAll("[^\\d.]+", ""));
```

This will convert "$13,465,398.09" to "13465398.09".

Comment: this worked! thanks, was definitely overthinking it!

Answer (score 0):

You could catch the `InputMismatchException` and either terminate the program with a message, or you could give `cost` some other value:

```
try {
    userExtraPercent = input.nextDouble();   
} catch (InputMismatchException e){ 
    System.out.println("Bad input");
    return;
}
```

Or, like you said, you could allow a $, but then you'd have to put some other parsing in (such as reading in with `next()` and filtering out bad characters), as `nextDouble()` would not work.

Answer (score 0):

heres my final code

```
      code = input.next(); // accepting user input
        System.out.print("Cost of single copy: " );
             cost1 = input.next().replaceAll("[^\\d.]+", ""); // Accounting for $
             double cost = Double.parseDouble(cost1); // converting cost to double
```